# Using windows file absolute path in react doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I tried using

```
<img src="file://C:/Users/JOHN-PC/Pictures/test123.png" alt="Logo"/>
```

in reactjs but the pic is not loading.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score 0):

Add `///` like below, this might help

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/JOHN-PC/Pictures/test123.png" alt="Logo"/>
```